# Passing values from the view to the controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have a Database table which holds number of Question rows. 
so I'm using this form to get questions from the database, when I press the the 'Next' Button it works perfectly.
but when I press the 'Prev' button it will always go to the first Question.
I need this to go to the previous Question. 
This is how my form looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Exam"))
    {

        @Html.Hidden("qid", Model.ID, new { @id = "id" })
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model.ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.QuestionDes
                </td>           
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>@Html.RadioButton("Answer1", new { @id = 1 })  @Model.Answer1 </p>
                </td>            
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>@Html.RadioButton("Answer2", new { @id = 2 })  @Model.Answer2 </p>
                </td>            
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>@Html.RadioButton("Answer3", new { @id = 3 })  @Model.Answer3 </p>
                </td>            
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>@Html.RadioButton("Answer4", new { @id = 4 })  @Model.Answer4 </p>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Next" />

    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("PrevIndex", "Exam"))
    {

        @Html.Hidden("qid1", Model.ID, new { @id = "id1" })
        <input value="Prev" type="submit"/>
    }
```

This how my Controller looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
    QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(1);
    //ViewBag.question = q;
    return View(q);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(QuestionLoadDTO ques)
{
    int count = 0;
    count = int.Parse(Request["qid"].ToString());
    count++;
    if (count <= 4)
    {
        IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
        QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(count);
        return View(q);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Submit");                               

}
public ActionResult PrevIndex(QuestionLoadDTO ques)
{
    int count1 = 0;
    count1 = int.Parse(Request["qid1"].ToString());
    count1--;
    if (count1 < 5 || count1 >= 0)
    {
        IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
        QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(count1);
        //return View(q);
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index",q);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("End");

}
public ActionResult Submit()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult End()
{
    return View();
}
```

These are my other methods:

```
QuestionLoadDTO IQuestionService.GetIndividualQuestions(int index)
{
    IQuestionData ser = new QuestionRepository();           

    QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQues(index);

    return q;
}
public QuestionLoadDTO GetIndividualQues(int index)
{
    Context con = new Context();
    Question question = con.Questions.Find(index);//Where(e => e.ID == index).FirstOrDefault();
    QuestionLoadDTO dto = new QuestionLoadDTO()
    {
        ID = question.ID,
        QuestionDes = question.QuestionDes,
        Answer1 = question.Answer1,
        Answer2 = question.Answer2,
        Answer3 = question.Answer3,
        Answer4 = question.Answer4

    };                                
    return dto;
}
```

Can someone please give me an idea to solve this. Thank You in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: no i'm not getting errors....

Comment: you have only 4 questions ?

Comment: when i press the previous button.. it always move to the first question... but i need it to go to the previous question element...

Comment: yes at the moment i have only 4 elements

Comment: you show only one question at a time ?

Comment: yes one question at a time

Comment: Hey dayan you missed to mention [HTTPPOST] in your 'public ActionResult PrevIndex' method please make sure is that causes the problem. let me know about it after you check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", q)
```

is not going to pass `q` because this method is effectively a client side redirection. And it also makes GET request, while you seemed to expect post overload of Index to be called. Which is not a great idea either - this action is  good for the purpose of handling form post, let's keep it like that.

I suggest to make the following changes:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int? qid)
{
    int index = qid == null ? 1 : qid;

    IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
    QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(index);
    //ViewBag.question = q;
    return View(q);
}
```

Get overload of the Index action now takes in optional index of the question to load. Now you can reuse this action to display any question you want.

```
public ActionResult PrevIndex(QuestionLoadDTO ques)
{
    int count1 = 0;
    count1 = int.Parse(Request["qid1"].ToString());
    count1--;
    if (count1 < 5 || count1 >= 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", count1);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("End");
}
```

No need to retrieve question here, just redirect to Index with appropriate question index.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `PrevIndex` like below you are returning view using `RedirectToActionPermanent` but model value is not accepted in index method.

```
return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index",q);
```

And your index method does not accept any argument

```
public ActionResult Index()
```

So you need to change

```
return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index",q);
```

To

```
return View("Index",q);
```

Change it like this

```
public ActionResult PrevIndex(QuestionLoadDTO ques)
    {
        int count1 = 0;
        count1 = int.Parse(Request["qid1"].ToString());
        count1--;
        if (count1 < 5 || count1 >= 0)
        {
            IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
            QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(count1);
            return View("index",q);

        }
        return RedirectToAction("End");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it......

```
public ActionResult PrevIndex(QuestionLoadDTO ques)
{
     int count1 = 0;
     count1 = int.Parse(Request["qid1"].ToString());
     count1--;
     if (count1 < 5 || count1 >= 0)
     {
          IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
          QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(count1);
          //return View(q);
          return View("Index",q);
     }
     return RedirectToAction("End");    
}
```

I just had to change the return "RedirectToAction" into return View("Index",q)....
Now when you press the "prev" button it perfectly moves to the previous question....